# Why am I getting a good accuracy even with an overfitted CNN model?

Tags: neural-networks, convergence, overfitting

I got a bad fit for my model and no convergence happened during the time of training. However, I still got an accuracy of 97%. Then, I trained my other model and got an accuracy of 91%. However the second model had a better fit and did converge.

I am confused which of the two would be better and how to interpret this result?

[image]

This model attained 91% even with that result

Comment: Maybe you can share the loss curves and how you decided on 'no convergence'?

Comment: Please take a look at my graph. Thank you!